Why when mocked predicate, return null pointer?
My predicate returns null pointer when it is executed.
My test code:
public class CompanyRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Mock
    private CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

    @Mock
    private CriteriaQuery<Company> criteriaQuery;

    @Mock
    private Root<Company> root;

    @Mock
    private TypedQuery<Company> typedQuery;
    
    @Mock
    private Path<Object> path;
    
    @Mock
    private Expression<Object> express;

    @InjectMocks
    private CompanyRepositoryImpl companyRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should find Company by CNPJ and return success")
    void findByCnpjSuccess() {
        String cnpj = "123456789";

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setCnpj(cnpj);

        List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
        companies.add(company);

        when(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Company.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        when(criteriaQuery.from(Company.class)).thenReturn(root);
        
        when(root.get("cnpj")).thenReturn(path);
        
        Predicate predicate = mock(Predicate.class);
        when(criteriaBuilder.and(any())).thenReturn(predicate);
        when(criteriaBuilder.equal(path, cnpj)).thenReturn(predicate);
        
        // Criando o Predicate corretamente
//      Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("cnpj"), cnpj);
        
        // Configurando o mock para retornar o Predicate criado
//      when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("cnpj"), cnpj)).thenReturn(predicate);
        
        when(entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)).thenReturn(typedQuery);
        when(typedQuery.getResultList()).thenReturn(companies);

        List<Company> result = companyRepository.findByCnpj(cnpj);

        assertEquals(1, result.size());
        assertEquals(cnpj, result.get(0).getCnpj());

        verify(entityManager).getCriteriaBuilder();
        verify(criteriaBuilder).createQuery(Company.class);
        verify(criteriaQuery).from(Company.class);
        verify(criteriaBuilder).equal(root.get("cnpj"), cnpj);
        verify(entityManager).createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        verify(typedQuery).getResultList();
    }

}

And my method tested
@Autowired
private EntityManager manager;

@Override
public List<Company> findByCnpj(String cnpj) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Company> query = builder.createQuery(Company.class);
    Root<Company> root = query.from(Company.class);
    
    Predicate predicate = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("cnpj"), cnpj));
    query.select(root).where(predicate);
    
    TypedQuery<Company> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(query);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}

I'm trying to execute a test with Mockito.

Please [edit] the post and add the complete stack trace. Please also highlight the line of code throwing the exception.

Your test is not really testing that the repository is finding anything. It just makes sure that the code calls the methods on the mock objects. The slightest change to your code under test will break the test. Such tests are more useful when executed against a real or in-memory database. You don't gain anything by mocking 100% of the class' collaborators (there's no logic left that would need testing).

A quick run through the code and I see that the "query.select(root)" is not mocked. You can try this:
when(criteriaQuery.select(root)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);


Thanks for the answer, my test is ok now
